# How to Detect the calling Source/Device from webapi?

Tags: android, ios, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am tracking the Web API execution time in the log table which works great but now the issue is that,  I also need to capture what source is calling the APIs. There are multiple sources like iPad, iPhone, Adroid Devices and PostMan clients etc are calling these APIs. I would like to track these devices. Would it possible to track something like this, Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the "User-Agent" header parameter.

> One common use of the term refers to a web browser telling a web site information about the browser and operating system

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent

Comment: I would note that OP may be interested to know there is a website that helps explain what the contents of the User Agent mean : [for example](http://www.useragentstring.com/Firefox6.0a2_id_18498.php)

Comment: User Agent gives information something like below which will not say what is the source of the caller like iPhone or Android device.  Is there a way to capture anything like that ? " UserAgent = {Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36} " bu